# How to use wildcard character(%) search on java.lang.Long value

Tags: java, sql

I have been trying to fire a query for wild card search on an Integer value in a database.
It is giving an exception.

```
select * from tcotet A  where  A.icont like '%7187%'
```

Here `icont` is integer in the database, and in the java class file it has been mapped to a `Long` value.

Is there any alternate way to use wild card search on an integer value?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: cast it as a text value then use wildcards as normal

Comment: It can't work as Integer fields don't work with wildcards. Actually I find it very strange to select integers using a wildcard like this...

Comment: I ask which database, because mysql (at least) _does_ allow this.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b389d/1

Comment: That said, it is still probably a bad idea...

Comment: I am using squirrel sql tool to access mainframe db.There is requirement from user to allow wildcard search on that field.

Comment: @Kon,could you please give me the query using cast.

Comment: @SudheerKumarS No, but here's pseudocode to send you on the right track. You will have to research how to do this for your particular language yourself: `Select myColumn AS nvarchar(255) colName WHERE colName like '%007'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kon said, you just need to cast the integer to a string. In DB2 SQL, you whould do it like this:

```
select * from tcotet A where cast(A.icont as char(12)) like '%7187%'
```

Note that (oddly), integer cannot be cast to varchar, so you need to use the char type.